# http://myurl/api/rest/categories is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree, rest-api, php-5.6

I want to get category tree in magento 1.9 using REST API using
 this code **http://myurl/api/rest/categories**
but i am getting error 404.
[image]

Please help me in to get over this error

Comment: Did you solve your issue? @ Anil

Answer (score 2):

Unless you haven't created any custom resource structure I'd say the 404 is valid since the route does actually not exist: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Products

> Product Categories
>   Retrieve the list of categories assigned to a product, assign, and unassign the category to/from the specific product.
>
> **Resource Structure:** http://magentohost/api/rest/products/:productId/categories

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557684/display-categories-and-their-subcategories-in-magento-using-rest-api