# Why category resource is not present in catalog? Also explain how to add category

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category-tree, rest-api

[image]

I want to retrive category tree in rest api but category is missing in resources.
While hitting  **127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest/category** got
message Request does not match any route.
Please tell how to add it in magento 1.9 and how to get category tree by rest api in magento 1.9 ?

Comment: Hey @AnilThakur - I think it would be easier and more helpful handle this topic in one question only (i.e. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212101/http-myurl-api-rest-categories-is-not-working) as it is stated already, that what you are looking for is just not present by default. Did you check out the resources linked in your other question?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner 
i am following the setps provided in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento?rq=1
but still issue not resolved

Comment: i am hitting the target url : magentohost/api/rest/categories/7 
but getting the error message : Request does not match any route.